# match single keyword from re.compile which has a list of keyword

Tags: python, regex

i have keywords like

```
cat="AUTHORISATION,FORTHCOMING BOARD MEETINGS,PREVIOUS BOARD MEETINGS,BOARD MEETINGS,BOARD MEETING,MINUTES,BOARD PAPERS,AGENDA,COMMUNITY PROFILES,FORTHCOMING GOVERNOR MEETINGS,PREVIOUS GOVERNOR MEETINGS,GOVERNOR MEETINGS,GOVERNOR MEETING,GOVERNOR,COUNCIL OF GOVERNORS,GOVERNING BODY MEETINGS,COMPARISON,APC SUMMARY OF DECISIONS"
```

i have some pre-processing like this

```
cat_list=cat.split(',')
cat_list=filter(None, cat_list)
cat_list=[s.strip() for s in cat_list]
cat_list=[re.sub('\r\n' , ' ', s) for s in cat_list]
cat_list=[re.sub(r'([^\s])\s([^\s])', r'\1+(.)+\2',x) for x in cat_list]
cat_list=[re.sub(r'([a-z][a-z]+)', r'(\1)',a,flags=re.I) for a in cat_list]
regexes_cat=[re.compile((r'(?:%s)' % '|'.join(cat_list)),re.IGNORECASE),]
```

which gives re.compile expressions in list for me to perform re.search
so the final regex pattern after processing looks like this

```
(?:(AUTHORISATION)|(FORTHCOMING)+(.)+(BOARD)+(.)+(MEETINGS)|(PREVIOUS)+(.)+(BOARD)+(.)+(MEETINGS)|(BOARD)+(.)+(MEETINGS)|(BOARD)+(.)+(MEETING)|(MINUTES)|(BOARD)+(.)+(PAPERS)|(AGENDA)|(COMMUNITY)+(.)+(PROFILES)|(FORTHCOMING)+(.)+(GOVERNOR)+(.)+(MEETINGS)|(PREVIOUS)+(.)+(GOVERNOR)+(.)+(MEETINGS)|(GOVERNOR)+(.)+(MEETINGS)|(GOVERNOR)+(.)+(MEETING)|(GOVERNOR)|(COUNCIL)+(.)+(OF)+(.)+(GOVERNORS)|(GOVERNING)+(.)+(BODY)+(.)+(MEETINGS)|(COMPARISON)|(APC)+(.)+(SUMMARY)+(.)+(OF)+(.)+(DECISIONS))
```

but i got results like this if i print group(0)

```
GOVERNORS-MEETINGS.ASP?P=GOVERNORS%27.COUNCIL.MEETINGS
```

so i searched and found that i have to use **?** to make it non-greedy but i am unable get the required output
which should be

```
GOVERNORS-MEETINGS
```

i am performing re.search against URL and text present on webpage

```
http://www.qehkl.nhs.uk/governors-meetings.asp?p=governors%27.council.meetings&s=main&ss=becoming.a.foundation.trust
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. What are you trying to match against?

Comment: i am checking with url of a page

Comment: What is the format of the URL? Are you sure you need regex here?

Comment: `SAFERSTAFFING` is not in the list of keywords. Please update the question. Besides, [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) might be more helpful than regex when parsing query strings.

Comment: Replace `r'\1+(.)+\2'` with `r'\1(.*?)\2'` and retry. I guess you use `re.search`, right?

Comment: ya i tried it and got result like this GOVERNORS-MEETINGS
MEETING where words are repeating

Comment: @PavanKumarTS: How come you got that output? [Look at **my demo**, it is working as you need](https://ideone.com/rESova).

Comment: Also, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/INuORx/1), the first match is correct.

Comment: if itry for this GOVERNORS/GOVERNORS-MEETINGS.ASP?P=GOVERNORS%27.COUNCIL.MEETINGS it prints GOVERNORS/GOVERNORS-MEETINGS

Comment: @PavanKumarTS: Correct, it is expected since you also match what is inbetween `GOVERNOR` and `MEETINGS`. Do you need to discard all that was captured? See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/Ml9CgW), does it work as expected?  Concat the first group with the second omitting the capture in between?

Comment: I really do not have a clue what the rule here is. See https://ideone.com/Ml9CgW

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks it works

Comment: Wait, no, it is incorrect. I suspect you need to only match inside the *last* part of the URL, before the query string, right? See https://ideone.com/DivFki.

Comment: .*? Will be good but I didn't get why [^/]*?

Comment: The answer below is incorrect. But in order to provide the best answer, please clarify: do you need `GOVERNORS-MEETINGS` in that position ->  *GOVERNORS/ **GOVERNORS-MEETINGS** .ASP?P=GOVERNORS%27.COUNCIL.MEETINGS*? In the last subpart of the path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144626/discussion-between-pavan-kumar-t-s-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I suggest is based on the following assumptions:

- The regex match should happen in the *last subpart* of the *path* (i.e. in the file part, before any eventual query string)
- The query string  is optional

So, the solution is to parse the URL first with `urlparse` to only get the string to run the regex on, and forget about lookarounds. Instead of `(.)+`, just use a lazy `(.*?)` to match any 0+ chars as few as possible:

```
import re
from urlparse import urlparse

cat="AUTHORISATION,FORTHCOMING BOARD MEETINGS,PREVIOUS BOARD MEETINGS,BOARD MEETINGS,BOARD MEETING,MINUTES,BOARD PAPERS,AGENDA,COMMUNITY PROFILES,FORTHCOMING GOVERNOR MEETINGS,PREVIOUS GOVERNOR MEETINGS,GOVERNOR MEETINGS,GOVERNOR MEETING,GOVERNOR,COUNCIL OF GOVERNORS,GOVERNING BODY MEETINGS,COMPARISON,APC SUMMARY OF DECISIONS"
cat_list=cat.split(',')
cat_list=filter(None, cat_list)
cat_list=[s.strip() for s in cat_list]
cat_list=[re.sub('\r\n' , ' ', s) for s in cat_list]
cat_list=[re.sub(r'([^\s])\s([^\s])', r'\1(.*?)\2',x) for x in cat_list] # Allow anything in between the keywords, but as few as possible
cat_list=[re.sub(r'([a-z][a-z]+)', r'(\1)', a, flags=re.I) for a in cat_list]
regex_cat=re.compile(r"(?:{})".format('|'.join(cat_list)),re.IGNORECASE)
#print(regex_cat.pattern)
urls = "GOVERNORS/GOVERNORS-MEETINGS.ASP?P=GOVERNORS%27.COUNCIL.MEETINGS "
o = urlparse(urls)                       # Parse the URL
last_subpart = o.path.split('/').pop()   # Get the last subpart
m = regex_cat.search(last_subpart)       # Run the regex search
if m:                                    # If there is a match...
    print(m.group())                     # Print or do anything with the value
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Mfjp9E)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code -

```
cat_list=cat.split(',')
cat_list=filter(None, cat_list)
cat_list=[s.strip() for s in cat_list]
cat_list=[re.sub('\r\n' , ' ', s) for s in cat_list]

#Till now all same, following statements have changes
cat_list=[re.sub(r'([^\s])\s([^\s])', r'\1+.+?\2',x) for x in cat_list]
cat_list=['(%s)'%re.sub(r'([a-z]+)', r'(\1)',a,flags=re.I) for a in cat_list]
regexes_cat=[re.compile((r'(?:%s)' % '|'.join(cat_list)),re.IGNORECASE),]
```

Here's the working [demo](http://ideone.com/1MxKRy).